# Which IP-addresses are used by the gcloud-tool?

Tags: firewall, google-compute-engine

I have an Google Compute Engine in a project where security policy states that outgoing network traffic is denied by default, required services are allowed by specific firewall rules.

I need to use the gcloud command line tool in the Compute Engine to take snapshots and perform other admin tasks.

Which IP-addressess/ports should be allowed for the gcloud-tool to function?

Answer (score 1):

To execute [gcloud](https://cloud.google.com/sdk/gcloud/) commands successfully you will need to allow this tool  communicate with Google API servers on this address: **www.googleapis.com**